# How to extract a part of a matrix according to dimension names

Tags: r, matrix, extract

I have a matrix, and there are dimensional names for each row and column.

How can I then extract a part of the matrix according to their specific dimension names? 
For example, extract an observation if the dimensional name contains some specific string in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with `[` and that the only difficulty you have is to find row names that match a certain pattern. You need to use `grep`. Here is an example where I select rows that contain "North":

```
USArrests[grep("North", rownames(USArrests)), ]
#                Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
# North Carolina   13.0     337       45 16.1
# North Dakota      0.8      45       44  7.3
```